# Who is the stakeholder of an user-driven application and what software methodology is suitable for it?

Tags: methodology, stakeholders

I'm new here and I am confused about something. Sorry if the question doesn't fit and not suitable here.

For the application like foursquare and yelp which focuses entirely on feedback of the user around the world instead of user in specific organization, who is their main stakeholder? What software methodologies would they use if their main stakeholder is the user instead of top management in an organization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The stakeholder(s) are those who are affected by the success or failure of the application. Users are stakeholders; if the application succeeds, then it will add value to their lives (and vice versa; if it adds value to their lives, it will likely succeed).

But there are other stakeholders.  The project team are stakeholders. The investors are stakeholders.

The user is unlikely to be the main stakeholder, because the user doesn't generally influence development until after the application is fielded.  My mind can't quite wrap around the question of the stakeholders choosing the software methodologies.  Reminds me of the "Camel is a horse designed by committee" quote. I think the norm would be that the software development team would choose the software methodology (constrained by what the company can license, and similar external factors).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, 4sq team includes a product owner, who is a proxy between user group and dev team. PO works with getting and structuring feedback, and together with analysts / or with co-working POs he elaborates on suggestions and structures the requirements. Then puts those requirements into backlog in the order that they are to be fulfilled.

It would be pretty easy to form sprints out of the tickets ranked according to their value inside the backlog. So it most likely is a basic scrum flow they use :)